# Troubles with lemon grammar (precedence?)

Tags: php, parser-generator, lemon

I'm having trouble with a simple grammar I have created to support function calls.
I am using the lemon-based PHP_ParserGenerator by Greg.

This is the relevant part of the grammar:

```
program ::= expr(A).                        { $this->result = A; }

value(A) ::= SIMPLE_STRING(B).              { A = B; }
value(A) ::= NUMBER(B).                     { A = B; }
value(A) ::= CONTEXT_REFERENCE(B).          { A = B; }

arg_list ::= arg_list SEPARATOR value(B).   { $this->args[] = B; }
arg_list ::= value(B).                      { $this->args[] = B; }
arg_list ::= . 

expr(A) ::= SIMPLE_STRING(B) PAREN_LEFT arg_list PAREN_RIGHT. { A = call_user_func_array(B, $this->args); }

expr(A) ::= CONTEXT_REFERENCE(B). {
    list($context, $key) = explode('.', B);
    A = $this->context[$context][$key]; 
}
```

When I initialize the parser with a context of `array('user' => array('name' => 'Dennis'));`  and execute the following code:

```
$parser->doParse(PelParser::CONTEXT_REFERENCE, 'user.name');
$parser->doParse(0, 0);
```

The `$result` is as follows: 'Dennis'. Life is good.

But when I supply a CONTEXT_REFERENCE as argument to a function call, it doesn't work:

```
$parser->doParse(PelParser::SIMPLE_STRING, 'str_replace');
$parser->doParse(PelParser::PAREN_LEFT, '(');
$parser->doParse(PelParser::SIMPLE_STRING, 'e');
$parser->doParse(PelParser::SEPARATOR, ',');
$parser->doParse(PelParser::NUMBER, 3);
$parser->doParse(PelParser::SEPARATOR, ',');
$parser->doParse(PelParser::CONTEXT_REFERENCE, 'user.name');
$parser->doParse(PelParser::PAREN_RIGHT, ')');
$parser->doParse(0, 0);
```

The `$result` is 'us3r.nam3'. Not quite as expected. For the record, the expected output is of course 'D3nnis'. (user.name **first** gets replaced with the string 'Dennis' and after that passed to the `str_replace()` function).

I suspect it has something to do with precedence. But I can't figure what I should change to make this. The very sparse Lemon documentation is not of very great help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer to my question.

When I change my grammar to:

```
program ::= expr(A).                        { $this->result = A; }

value(A) ::= SIMPLE_STRING(B).              { A = B; }
value(A) ::= NUMBER(B).                     { A = B; }
value(A) ::= CONTEXT_REFERENCE(B). {
    // B=='{context}.{name}' 
    list($context, $key) = explode('.', B);
    A = $this->context[$context][$key]; 
}

arg_list ::= arg_list SEPARATOR value(B).   { $this->args[] = B; }
arg_list ::= value(B).                      { $this->args[] = B; }
arg_list ::= . 

expr(A) ::= SIMPLE_STRING(B) PAREN_LEFT arg_list PAREN_RIGHT. { A = call_user_func_array(B, $this->args); }
```

It seems to work as expected.
The problem was that I created an ambiguity in the first grammar:

```
value(A) ::= CONTEXT_REFERENCE(B).          { A = B; }

expr(A) ::= CONTEXT_REFERENCE(B). {
    list($context, $key) = explode('.', B);
    A = $this->context[$context][$key]; 
}
```

I'll leave the question and answer here so others might benefit from my mistakes :)
If somebody has anything to share, please do.